Romance film, girl in love with character in boyfriend's book
I cannot remember the movie where a girl falls for another guy throughout the whole movie and it makes you feel really bad for her boyfriend (who is a writer) because he loves her so much yet the girl is drifting towards this other guy. In the end we find out that the other man IS  her boyfriend but as a character in his novel... Anyone ANY idea?
I would think it was a 2000+ movie but I can't be sure... it was well made so I don't think it was a low budget film but I don't know about the Hollywood thing either. I didn't know any of the actors in it so that makes me think possibly an independent film.

I'm not sure I understand the it was a character part. Are you saying this man was pretending to be a character from a book he wrote, or she was imagining him and he was from a book she read?

I don't know if my English is that bad of what but i can't understand what you want to say. Please elaborate who is who.

sorry, i edited it to try and explain a little clearer... im sorry i can't put in much detail but i watched it over two years ago and have little memory of it

Kinda sounds like "Ruby Sparks" - http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1839492/ , but it doesn't fit quite the details. Watch a trailer for the movie, maybe you remembered some of the facts wrong.

definitely not "ruby sparks"... throughout the movie you don't even remember that he is a writer or that its a fictional character till the end

How old would you say this movie is? Is it a Hollywood movie? Do you remember anything else?

i would think it was a 2000+ movie but i can't be sure... it was well made so i don't think it was a low budget film but i don't know about the Hollywood thing either. My girlfriend at the time had me watch it so i really didn't get the name even then. i didn't know any of the actors in it so that makes me think possibly an independent film.

OK, added the info and posted a possible match.

This could be My Girlfriend's Boyfriend from 2010 with Alyssa Milano. From IMDb:

would be-author Ethan Reed, devoted to his sister's family, feels he met his soul-mate in confident, understanding waitress Jesse Young [...] In parallel, without them ever meeting, Jesse is accidentally found by and enjoys perfect dates set up by dream prince Troy Parker, a handsome, rich, famous, suave gentleman advertisement agency co-owner

And in the end, according to Wiki:

It is revealed at this point that the relationship between Jesse and Troy was fictional; Troy had been created by Ethan as a more wealthy and successful version of himself for his novel.

The entire movie is currently available on Youtube here, and here's the trailer:




Perfect that's it! thank you so much... and I know Alyssa Milano, dunno how i forgot she was in it.

@Tyj22 No problem. :) Don't forget to close the question by clicking on the check mark.
